# Making AUCTeX aware of the TeX engine set in master file

Tags: emacs, auctex

Is there a way to make AUCTeX aware of the TeX engine local variable set in a master file when I compile from other files?

`master.tex`:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\begin{document}
  \input{content}
\end{document}

%%% Local Variables:
%%% mode: latex
%%% TeX-engine: luatex
%%% End:
```

`content.tex`:

```
Here is some content.

%%% Local Variables: 
%%% mode: latex
%%% TeX-master: "master"
%%% End:
```

When I am inside `content.tex` and pres `C-c C-c`, AUCTeX runs `pdflatex` and not `lualatex`.

Comment: Some comment (bit off topic): no need for `minimal` in the MWE, we prefer `article` (or `scrartcl`) for instance.

Comment: For now, I'd just set it in the child files as well: `TeX-engine` is local to a buffer by default, and that variable does not seem to be parsed and added to the 'auto' sub-directory by default. (I assume this is an oversight that should be corrected.)  Meanwhile, you can simply do a `TeX-engine-set` <RET> luatex <RET>` to make `content.tex` switch engines, which I'm sure you know already.  It is likewise easy to set `luatex` as your default engine for all files, too.  (Better Emacs hackers will hopefully chime in with a real answer.)

Comment: Just as a design thought for a hero who writes up a solution: perhaps it would be good to create an alist (say, `TeX-inherited-variables-alist`) of variables to inherit from the file-local variables of the master.  There is no such ready-made function, but you can grep for `Local Variables:` in `files.el` to find the sexp that handles it.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If *all* LaTeX files in this directory will use the same engine, then you can set `TeX-engine` for all of them using [Emacs per-directory local variables](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Directory-Variables.html). Create a file in this directory named `.dir-locals.el` with the following contents:

```el
((latex-mode
  (TeX-engine . luatex)))
```

If all LaTeX files in this directory share the same master, then per-directory local variables are a convenient place to set this too:

```el
((latex-mode
  (TeX-engine . luatex)
  (TeX-master . "master")))
```

I find this more convenient than adding `Local variables:` sections to the end of each individual file. Of course, you can still use per-file local variables to override any of these if there are a few exceptional files to which these settings should not apply.

Comment: Ah, brilliant!  Could've used this about a million times before now...